# Submitting form & preventing default action doesn't work

Tags: vue.js

Imagine you have a form and the submit button which are placed in separate places, so that the submit button is not inside form tag. I need to submit the form without reloading the whole page.

I got is like this:

```
<form id="myForm" @submit.prevent="doSomething()">...</form>
<button @click="submitMyForm()"></button>
```

And the methods:

```
methods: {
    submitMyForm() {
        $('#myForm').submit();
    },

    doSomething() {
        console.log('do something');
    }
}
```

But I got the form submitted anyway. 
So how to submit the form when the button is outside the form?

Answer (score 1):

well, calling `.submit()`. In the form element will submit the form. Instead, do an an ajax request. That does not magically happen on its own.

Comment: And when I submit the form, the submission should be prevented due to @submit.prevent, right?

Comment: The `.prevent` modificator will prevent the normal HTTP-POST Submit of the form that would be done by the browser's default behaviour, yes.